# How to Kill a Thread with TID on Android Platform

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I use a third part library to do some heavy work asynchronously with a thread.If the user quit the that activity, I want to kill the thread that created by third library. I only get the TID from the library. Is there any method to kill a thread with his TID?

I've found tkill system call on Linux. How can I invoke tkill from java code?